# How to do the following recursive sum?

Tags: excel, sum

I am trying to do the following in excel. I want F2=E2, F3=E3+F2, F4=E4+F3, F5=E5+F4, ... and so on.

I was wondering how I can do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
=F1+E2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft Excel, you should be able to start with F2=E2, F3=SUM($F$2:$F3) + E3, F4=SUM($F$2:$F4) + E4; and the highlight F3 and F4; then drag the lower right corner of the box down and it will match the recursive arithmetic sequence.

Source
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/699256-is-it-possible-to-create-a-recursive-formula.html